# Query Directory roles of a user in Azure Graph API

Tags: azure, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to query the roles (Directory Role) of a user (I have ObjectId and the UPN of the user) by just calling the Graph API once!

I'm able to query a user and then use that user to get the DirectoryRoles, but for performance reasons I need to drop the first GET user call.

I have looked at this endpoint but this seems to just work for security groups not Directory Roles (like Company Administrator etc)

```
https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/{resource_collection}/{resource_id}/checkMemberGroups?api-version
```

And there is the endpoint that returns all the groups (Directory Roles and Groups) but for big tenants it won't perform well as it returns data I don't need.

```
https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/{resource_collection}/{resource_id}/getMemberObjects?api-version
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to work out how to get a user and it's memberships in one call using the 2.1.0 .Net Azure Graph SDK:

Here is the code to do it:

```
    var client = _tokenHelper.GetActiveDirectoryClient(user.User.DomainName);
    var memberof = await client.Users.GetByObjectId(user.User.UserKey).MemberOf.ExecuteAsync();
```